# Bottle Server not working on Centos

Tags: python, apache, bottle

I wrote a bottle application on windows and moved it to a centos server that is also running an apache web server. I have bottle running:

```
Bottle v0.12.9 server starting up (using GeventServer())...
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

Whenever I try to send a request to the server with curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/bottle/main.py it responds with this:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 18:59:29 GMT
Content-Length: 233
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/bottle/main.py was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

And there is no activity shown on the server. I think that somehow apache is usurping the request or something, but I have no idea. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how bottle works, If your code looks like this example:

```
import bottle

@bottle.route("/hello")
def func():
    return "hello!!!!!!!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bottle.run(port=8080)
```

Then browse to http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello

> hello!!!!!!!